# Iterating through large pandas DataFrame (5 million rows) with semi-complex function? [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, recommendation-engine

I'm creating a recommender system based on Goodreads data. I collect the initial user's books and ratings under variable `ratings`. I then have a DataFrame with reviews of the top 10,000 books on Goodreads in `goodreads_dataset`.

When concatenating the two DataFrame and trying to convert to a pivot table (to make recommendations), i get an error as the number of cells exceeds the upper limit of int32 (over 3 billion cells).

My proposed solution is to remove all users from `goodreads_dataset` who don't have at least 1 common book with the initial user. However, it takes way too long to remove all these users from the DataFrame.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Here is my initial attempt:

```
def df_users(user):
    return set(goodreads_dataset.query(f'user_id == "{user}"')['book_id'])

def selecting_similar_users(user):
    return (df_users(user) & set(ratings.keys())) != set([])

goodreads_dataset['similar'] = goodreads_dataset['user_id'].apply(lambda x: selecting_similar_users(x))
```

I'm putting it in a column for now as a test, but I've run this for 10 min with no result.

Next I tried a vectorized solution to speed things up:

```
goodreads_dataset['similar'] = selecting_similar_users(goodreads_dataset['user_id'])
```

This returns "ValueError: multi-line expressions are only valid in the context of data, use DataFrame.eval
".

I also tried creating a generator with using a for loop and yielding the boolean value, but that also takes forever. Basically, all of the high-speed iteration methods I've tried have either given me errors or been too slow.

However, if there is another solution to the pivot-table problem then I'd be able to forego this step, as there can be a situation where even the reduced DataFrame would be too large for a pivot table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you make `ratings` a dataframe you can use `.isin()` to filter out non-matching users e.g. `user_ids = df.loc[df['book_id'].isin(ratings['book_id']), 'user_id']; df.loc[ df['user_id'].isin(user_ids) ]` - It may also help to call `.unique()` on the user_ids before the 2nd `.isin()`. The error is because you're trying to passing the Series into `.query()` which is not valid.